# Spring Boot run hierarchical profiles configuration

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I have the following Spring project structure (which I cannot change):

```
project/
    config/
        us/
            dev.yml
            stg.yml
        dev.yml
        stg.yml
    src/
        main/
            java/
            resources/
                application.yml
```

I'd like to run the following hierarchical profiling: `application.yml`, then override with `dev.yml`, and again override with `us/dev.yml`. I have no clue on how to perform this succesfully

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `ApplicationContextInitializer` that would read those files using `YamlPropertySourceLoader`. It could then set them up as property sources in the required order, using `ConfigurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst()`:

```java
public class YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer
        implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
        try {
            YamlPropertySourceLoader sourceLoader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();

            Resource usDev = ctx.getResource("project/config/us/dev.yml");
            sourceLoader.load("us_dev", usDev).forEach(propertySource
                    -> ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(propertySource));

            Resource dev = ctx.getResource("project/config/dev.yml");
            sourceLoader.load("dev", dev).forEach(propertySource ->
                    ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(propertySource));

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You can add this initializer to your application class as follows:

```java
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
app.addInitializers(new YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer());
app.run();
```

If you need to include those files based on some enabled Spring profile, you can consult the property `ctx.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()` and add those files conditionally.

Comment: Is there any solution which does not imply any kind of coding?

Comment: Not that I know of. Spring Boot has some conventions as to how the profile configuration files have to be named and where they should be located. If you can’t change anything about your configuration structure, you’ll need to write some extensions.